# PowerDesigner 16 - generate a list of tables and column definitions

Tags: reporting, powerdesigner

Does anyone know how to generate a simple report showing all tables in a model, and their columns (name and a few attributes including NOT NULL)?  I worked through the Report Wizard and got totally confused.

Comment: You create a Report (not using the "Use legacy Report Editor"), drag the Table folder to the report. Then using the Outline, remove all items except "List of columns of the table"; on this node, use "Edit Attributes" to add "Mandatory", remove "Name". Use the report view, to remove the "Key Indicator". And voila!

Comment: When you say "drag the Table folder to the report", I know where the Table folder is, but I don't know what you mean by "the report."  PD is open to the Data Model, and the Object browser (containing the Table folder) appears on the left-hand side.  Can you take me from there?  (Edit: in fact, the Table folder in the Object Browser doesn't seem to be draggable at all.)

Comment: No, I mean the Table folder in the Report Toolbox... oops... I've just hidden it, and I don't know how to bring it back... OK.. View > Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the previous answer to be very clear.

1. Select the model from the object browser.
2. Select Report -> List Report Wizard from the main menu.
3. Select "EntityAttribute" (logical model) or "Column" (physical model) in the Object Type field of the dialog box and click Next.
4. Select the columns to include in the report [(example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBa0C.jpg) and click Next.
5. Select the filter and/or sort columns, if any, and click Next.
6. Enter a name for the List Report and check the "Generate the list report to an external file" [(example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQve2.jpg) if you want the report written to a file, and then click the Finish.